# index of a character in a js string doesn't work for some strings

Tags: javascript, outlook

So, in my application, there is an option for users to enter remarks. I have some validation code written in javascript to remove the double quotes and single quotes from the same, so that it can be saved properly in database.

```
        var s2 = document.getElementById("txtMRCommentEntry").value;
    var result = s2.indexOf('"');
```

This code works fine if I manually enter the data to the textbox, or paste it from word, pdf etc. I get the index returned properly for validation.

But in case of copying the text from outlook and pasting it into the textbox, the indexOf function doesn't work. It returns -1, no matter what text I copy from outlook.

I am unsure what the issue is, and if anyone every faced the same.

Comment: Try s2.indexOf('\"')

Comment: Check what the quotes are in the text that you pasted. It's likely that it contains curly quotes instead of the plain quotes.

Comment: This is the text I copied from outlook. (asadas”asdad) I think it might be that curly quotes issue.

Comment: Yep, it was the curly quotes issue. Wonder why it worked with MS word though, as even that curls the quotes. :/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I can't just use " for validation as outlook curls the quote. Added a check for “ and ” too. Now everything is fine.

Thanks a lot, Mr. Guffa

Also, I couldn't just do indexOf for a curly quote. Here is the updated code in case someone else need it.

```
        var commentString = document.getElementById("txtMRCommentEntry").value;
    commentString = commentString.replace(/\u201C/g, "&#8220;").replace(/\u201D/g, "&#8221;");
    var result = commentString.indexOf('"');
    if (result == "-1") {
        result = commentString.indexOf('&#8220;');
    }
    if (result == "-1") {
        result = commentString.indexOf('&#8221;');
    }
    if (result != "-1") {
        alert("Please remove double quotes from the description");
        return false;
    }
```